# Using " * " for multiplication of binary numbers, only gives me addition, why? (Code here)

Tags: verilog, integer-arithmetic

I'm learning operations with " + ", " - " and " * ", addition and subtraction works well, but multiplication gives me only additions, link for the code:

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/NvT

I checked the code, can't understand what's going on. I gave enough space (bits) the result variable.

BTW, It's a code intended for fixed-point operations including fractional numbers, but everything is calculated as integers.

Comment: Your inputs (valor_a) are 16 bit but assign 32bits in the testbench.

Comment: Thank you Morgan. I received a -1 in the evaluation. I wish to know if there is something wrong in the formulation of my question, to be aware next time before making another in order to comply with forum rules. Thanks again.

Comment: I would not worry about the -1, close votes are the real hint that some thing is truly wrong. Next time I would include the code snippet in the question, so that it can stand on its own if EDA Playground goes offline. Often converting your code snippet to the minimal viable problem which shows your issue is really helpful. In this case it would just be a minimal example of multiplication with the addition and subtraction code removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your select signal is only on 1bit.
Then when you set select = 2 it assigns the lower bit of 2(2'b10) i.e. 0.
You should change select declaration by :

```
input [1:0] select; // In the module  
reg   [1:0] select; // In the testbench
```

To avoid such errors I would advise you to use the complete notation of values:

```
x'tnnn...nnn
```

where x is the width of the signal, t is the type (d for decimal, h for hexa, b for binary,...) and nnn...nnn the value in the type specified.

For example for the decimal value 2 you will have several notations that will make sense in certain situations:

```
2'd2 //2 bits decimal
2'h2 //2 bits hexadecimal  
2'b10//2 bits binary
```

For more informations about these notations you can read [this pdf](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~traylor/ece474/lecture_verilog/beamer/verilog_number_literals.pdf).

Comment: I got it fixed, first stages of learning are so difficult, thanks so much Krouitch.

Comment: My pleasure, I know how frustrating these tiny errors can be. Do not hesitate to ask questions if you are not sure. 
Little side point:
In order to obtain a correct design it is in my opinion almost mandatory to think of the hardware that will be generated by your code, like a sort of synthesis tool.
Once you can "think" in hardware it become much more natural to develop correct designs. [This](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/index.html) website is quite good for it as it translates simple examples into a gate level.